# ¿Es correcta esta regla de los 30 minutos?

Tags: discusión

Hola quería consultar si una regla que trato de seguir es buena o no para stackoverflow español.
La regla es la siguiente, antes de hacer una pregunta estoy 30 minutos buscando por mi mismo la respuesta, y si no tengo indicios de dar con la respuesta entonces hago la pregunta. Si tengo indicios, entonces continuo buscando por mi mismo la respuesta y entonces pasa más tiempo hasta que hago la pregunta o termino por mi mismo encontrando la respuesta.

Comment: Me parece una buena regla para tu uso personal. Cada uno puede setear su propio tiempo (30, 60, 120 minutos o 1 día, quién sabe). Yo creo que hay otros elementos que acompañan a publicar la pregunta: conocimiento del tema, cuan novedoso, si es algo popular o está con todo el hype de la comunidad o, por el contrario, está desfasado y requiere conocimiento muy particular, cuánto público podría atender mi pregunta, entenderla y sobretodo responderla. También si es un problema de programación (implementación), diseño (asociaciones entre clases/interfaces), arquitectura, etc. Y la lista sigue...

Answer (score 3):

[Luiggi Mendoza](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/227/luiggi-mendoza) comentó una buena respuesta a la pregunta:

> Me parece una buena regla para tu uso personal. Cada uno puede setear su propio tiempo (30, 60, 120 minutos o 1 día, quién sabe).
>
> Yo creo que hay otros elementos que acompañan a publicar la pregunta: conocimiento del tema, cuan novedoso, si es algo popular o está con todo el hype de la comunidad o, por el contrario, está desfasado y requiere conocimiento muy particular, cuánto público podría atender mi pregunta, entenderla y sobretodo responderla. También si es un problema de programación (implementación), diseño (asociaciones entre clases/interfaces), arquitectura, etc.
>
> Y la lista sigue...